# Data Binding fails

Tags: data-binding, bindingsource

I have a form with 30 fields of data on it - mostly TextBox controls displaying string data, but there are 3 dropdownlist comboboxes and one textbox used to display a datetime.  I'm using a BindingSource to bind these fields to a custom data object derived from BindingList<>.

Depending on the content of the data in the data source, sometimes a specific field will simply fail to bind - meaning the data from the data source does not get moved to the control.  The control that fails is a simple textbox.text / string binding.

I can perform a specific query that in every instance will cause this specific field to fail to bind.  I have other queries that can be performed that produce a set of data where the bindings all work perfectly.

My question is - what causes data binding to fail?  Will the failure of some other bound field stop all the other bindings from firing?

Comment: What does the failing query look like?  What does the passing query look like?  Can you post samples? There should be some identifiable difference between the two.

Comment: @Robert - The query isn't what is failing.  It's the binding that is failing.  When I debug into the code at the point the bindings are firing, I can SEE data in the property (it's a LAST NAME field) of the current object in the collection / BindingSource. It simply isn't being moved FROM the data object TO the UI control.

There is nothing unusual about that piece of data - its a 4-char displayable name.

I'm also not getitng any binding exceptions or binding errors.  I'm getting a successful BindingComplete on every field, but the data simply isn't in the control.  

I'm losing hair.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by writing my own binding infrastructure.  That gave me more explicit control over when bindings fired and what happened as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things that you could check

- Is there a mismatch in the size of the data field and the field in the UI
- Are there any special characters in the data
- Is the code that binds the fields not being run in certain circumstances
- Is there some code that is clearing the binding